# The pyvirtualdisplay Error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

I'm getting the following error when i try to run the python code 
File_1.py actually import File_2.py to call the function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "File_1.py", line 1, in <module>
import File_2
File "/home/eduser/shashank/File_2.py", line 8, in <module>
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", 
line 34, in __init__
self._obj = self.display_class(
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", 
line 52, in display_class
cls.check_installed()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 
38, in check_installed
ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 
180, in check_installed
raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
OSError=None
Program install error!
```

here is the section of code to which the error points

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import File_3_1

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to have `xvfv` installed. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb xserver-xephyr vnc4server
```

See: http://pyvirtualdisplay.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation